# How do I get my app to appear in the Applications list?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, desktop-environment, packaging, application

I have created a .deb package that copies files to the `/opt/MyAppName` directory. However, it does not appear in the Applications list, and I am unsure how to make that happen.

[image]

How do I make my app appear in this list? I would like to have this appear here for all users who use install the .deb when I publish it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a `your_application.desktop` file and then copy to `/usr/share/applications/`. Following is a sample `.desktop` file, I recently used to create `sublime_text.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Sublime Text
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text %F
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=/opt/sublime_text/Icon/128x128/sublime-text.png
Categories=TextEditor;Development;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Window;Document;

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=New Window
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text -n
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Document]
Name=New File
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text --command new_file
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Give attention to `Exec=` and `Icon=`

Comment: Is there somewhere where I can find more about what each of these properties mean? I think that there are some that are necessary for a text editor, but not my app.

Comment: Most of the lines are kind of self explanatory. Try, https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en